# Extjs combobox - getting json deeper values

Tags: json, extjs, combobox

For internal reasons, I have to send back from the server to the combo the following json string:

```
{"root":[{"employeeId":1,"user":{"userName":"admin"}}]}
```

As you can see, the user is actually an object, any way that the combobox will be able to read it?
the combo is configured as the following:

```
      ,displayField:'user.userName'
          ,title:'Manager'
          ,xtype: 'numberfield'
          ,hiddenName:  'employeeId'
          ,valueField : 'employeeId'
```

this is the store:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    url: "/some_data",
    root: 'root',   
    methos:'POST',
    fields:[{name:"employeeId"},{name:"user.userName"}] });
```

the ext wont render it, any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'mapping' property on fields in your store to remap the "deep" values to simple names the ComboBox can then reference:

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Manager',
    hiddenName: 'employeeId',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root: 'root',
        url: '/some_data',
        method: 'POST',
        fields: [
            {name: 'employeeId'},
            {name: 'userName', mapping: 'user.userName'}
        ]
    }),
    displayField: 'userName',
    valueField: 'employeeId'
});
```

Comment: I would suspect then that one of the records in the JSON response might be missing the user property. A more thorough example showing the full JSON data and how it is being loaded into the store would be helpful.